# Intercambiar el valor de dos variables en java

Tags: java, array, variables

estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo un problema sencillo para el que intento crear un método que me intercambie dos variables pero me encuentro con que mi código no hace lo que yo espero, ¿alguien me puede decir a que se debe? Muchas gracias:

```
public class insertaEnOrdenado{

static void intercambiar (int i, int j){
  int aux=i;
  i=j;
  j=aux;
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   

//prueba
      int i=0;
      int j=1;
      int [] arr5 = {1,2};
      System.out.println (arr5[i]);
      System.out.println (arr5[j]);
      intercambiar (i,j);
      System.out.println (arr5[i]);
      System.out.println (arr5[j]);
```

Aquí me debería devolver al principio el array 1,2, y después el 2,1, pero me devuelve 1,2 ambas veces. ¿Alguien me puede explicar mi fallo?

Comment: Si alguna respuesta te resolivió tu duda, márcala como aceptada con el tick junto a los votos de esa pregunta. Si no, puedes dejarles comentarios indicando qué te falló al usar sus soluciones. Así habrá más posibilidades de recibir una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación de tu problema

En java se podría decir que hay 3 tipos de variables

**Variables locales**

> Las variables definidas dentro de métodos, constructores o bloques se denominan variables locales. La variable se declarará e inicializará dentro del método y **la variable se destruirá cuando el método se haya completado**.

**Variables de instancia**

> Las variables de instancia son variables dentro de una clase pero fuera de cualquier método. Estas variables se inicializan cuando se crea una instancia de la clase. Se puede acceder a las variables de instancia desde dentro de cualquier método, constructor o bloques de esa clase en particular.

**Variables de clase**

> Las variables de clase son variables declaradas dentro de una clase, fuera de cualquier método, con la palabra reservada *static*.

↑↑↑ Traducción del texto de [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-variable-shadowing-in-java) ↑↑↑

## También debes saber

Que una variable realmente te indica el espacio de memoria que ocupa tu dato, por lo que para cambiar el valor de dos variables se debería de cambiar lo que hay en el espacio de memoria. Para ello te explicaré que en la programación (en general) puedes enviar valores de un método o función a otro mediante el:

**Paso por referencia**: Le mandas la ubicación de memoria de tu variable

**Paso por valor**: Le mandas el valor que almacena tu variable almacenándose esta en una nueva ubicación de memoria

Para este caso, debes saber que java sólo tiene **paso por valor**, por lo que debemos debemos de asegurarnos que se pueda acceder desde ambos métodos, por lo cual de una vez descartamos una variable local como posibilidad y ya que tu ***main*** es estático, se descarta una variable de instancia.

## Código

```java
public class Main {

    static int a, b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = 5;
        b = 10;
        changeValues();
        System.out.println("a: " + a + "\tb: " + b);
    }

    public static void changeValues() {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
a: 10   b: 5
```

Answer (score -1):

De tu código deduzco que lo que pretendes es ordenar los números de un array y  si es posible podrías ordenarlos de manera ascendente o descendente con el método burbuja en internet es fácil encontrarlo. Y para este ejemplo simple lo que podrías hacer es plantearlo de forma diferente y poner dos bucles .

```
    int array[]={1,2};
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<2;++i){
            System.out.println("Array original:"+array[i]);
        }
         
        
          for(int j=1;j>=0;--j){
            System.out.println("Array intercambiado: "+array[j]);
          }
```

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de intercambio de dos números.

```
 static void intercambiar(int x,int y){
        int aux=x;
         x=y;
         System.out.println(y);
         y=aux;
         System.out.println(aux);
    
    
    
}
```